# Issue with logical operations with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime
import numpy as np

stock = '^GSPC'
start = datetime.date(2018,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo',start, end)
```

This generates the following:

```
                   High          Low  ...      Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                         
2018-01-02  2695.889893  2682.360107  ...  3367250000  2695.810059
2018-01-03  2714.370117  2697.770020  ...  3538660000  2713.060059
2018-01-04  2729.290039  2719.070068  ...  3695260000  2723.989990
2018-01-05  2743.449951  2727.919922  ...  3236620000  2743.149902
2018-01-08  2748.510010  2737.600098  ...  3242650000  2747.709961
                ...          ...  ...         ...          ...
2020-04-08  2760.750000  2663.300049  ...  5856370000  2749.979980
2020-04-09  2818.570068  2762.360107  ...  7880140000  2789.820068
2020-04-13  2782.459961  2721.169922  ...  5274310000  2761.629883
2020-04-14  2851.850098  2805.100098  ...  5567400000  2846.060059
2020-04-15  2801.879883  2761.540039  ...  5203390000  2783.360107

[575 rows x 6 columns]
```

We have the following Boolean logic:

```
(data['Close'].shift(2) < data['Open'].shift(1)) & (data['Close'].shift(1) > data['Open'].shift(2))
```

The logic goes like this:
 yesterday's close > today's open `and` today's close > yesterday's open.

A picture to describe what i am trying to do look like this:

But when i run the boolean it gives me:

```
   2020-04-03     True
```

That is not correct, it should look like the picture. I am sure there is a problem with the boolean logic. I would appreciate any help you can offer in terms of the logic i have used.

---

I want a output as a series something like this:

```
2020-04-03     True
2020-04-06    False
2020-04-07    False
2020-04-08    False
2020-04-09    False
2020-04-13    False
2020-04-14    False
2020-04-15    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: please put an example of what you are expecting as output

Comment: As requested i have updated the question

Comment: please, re-check your execution, because I ran your code and get exactly this output. My pandas_datareader version is 0.8.1

Comment: Why `shift(1)` for today and `shift(2)` for yesterday, isn't it `shift(0)` for today and `shift(1)` for yesterday?

Comment: @Keldorn it depends which time of the day you are executing the code. if the code is for example executed during the trading hours it would not give me the EOD closing data. This way it would be definitely get EOD data only

Comment: @lalfab But the output is not correct because `yesterday's close > today's open and today's close > yesterday's open`  is what i am looking for

Comment: Your code contradicts with your statement. Your code: `(data['Close'].shift(2) < data['Open'].shift(1)) & (data['Close'].shift(1) > data['Open'].shift(2))` vs. your statement:  yesterday's close > today's open and today's close > yesterday's open --> The output is correct

Comment: @CodePope Thank for your help! I think you have solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your condition to `(data['Close'].shift(2) > data['Open'].shift(1)) & (data['Close'].shift(1) > data['Open'].shift(2))`.
Here a sample:

```
data['Closeshift2'] = data['Close'].shift(2)
data['OpenShift1'] = data['Open'].shift(1)
data['CloseShift1'] = data['Close'].shift(1)
data['OpenShift2'] = data['Open'].shift(2)
data['Bool']  = (data['Closeshift2'] > data['OpenShift1']) & (data['CloseShift1'] > data['OpenShift2'])
data[-11:-8]
```

which results in:

```
            High        Low         Open        Close       Volume      Adj Close   Closeshift2 OpenShift1  CloseShift1 OpenShift2  Bool
Date                                            
2020-04-01  2522.750000 2447.489990 2498.080078 2470.500000 5947900000  2470.500000 2626.649902 2614.689941 2584.590088 2558.979980 True
2020-04-02  2533.219971 2455.790039 2458.540039 2526.899902 6454990000  2526.899902 2584.590088 2498.080078 2470.500000 2614.689941 False
2020-04-03  2538.179932 2459.959961 2514.919922 2488.649902 6087190000  2488.649902 2470.500000 2458.540039 2526.899902 2498.080078 True
```

which is the result you showed in your picture

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and helpful answer, it is exactly what i was looking for !